# add new associative into existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myVar = {a:1,b:2};
```

how to add c programmatically?

I can do like this but it produce duplicate codes

```
var myVar = {a:1,b:2};
if(AddC()){
myVar = {a:1,b:2,c:3};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myVar = {a:1,b:2};
if(AddC()){
  myVar.c = 3;
}
```